# How to make assertions on request body axios.js in Node.js doing real HTTP calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, jestjs, nock

I am making request with `axios.js` library and part of my integration test suite are expectations on data send in `body` of `POST` request, done by `axios`, to see if it's ok. During development I'he used `nock.js` and put expectations inside `.post` nock method, like this:

```
it('test signature should be present' , done => {
  ...
  nock...
    .post('', body => {
      const requestBody = JSON.parse(body);
      expect(requestBody.config.signature).toEqual('TEST SIGNATURE');
      done();
    ...
  })
...
});
```

but need also to have integration tests that doesn't use `nock` with command

```
export NOCK_OFF='true' && jest
```

thus need a method to get request data and write expectations for it.

How this can be achieved?

**P.S.** I can imagine adding some custom `axios` interceptor in each test case before making HTTP call and removing it after test assertions, but it seems a lot of code for such thing. Or having some test helper that will store in its state data from the response and assert some things against it.

**P.P.S.** Possible variant is to spawn some HTTP Proxy and somehow catch requests and do assertions on them. But this is engineering overkill.

**P.P.S.** There may be a need for this testing flow though, but this is different question.